# Can't set UserId and RoleId with different type in IdentityUserRole<T>

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2.0.0-beta1. And I found IdentityUserRole could only specify the same foreign key type for both UserId and RoleId:

```
  public class IdentityUserRole<TKey>
  {
    public IdentityUserRole();

    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
  }
```

What I need is that UserId is string type and RoleId is int type.
I really need IdentityUserRole<> to support two generic type like:

```
  public class IdentityUserRole<TUserKey, TRoleKey>
  {
    public IdentityUserRole();

    public virtual TRoleKey RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual TUserKey UserId { get; set; }
  }
```

Thanks,
Kriss

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a different type for Users and Roles?